# xpath for tag with similar class and tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy, css-selectors

[image]
[website](https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/274411/bucatini-cacio-e-pepe-roman-sheep-herders-pasta/)

The tags that are marked
in yellow have the text for which I want the XPATH
I got the XPATH for first tag using:

```
'//div[@class="recipe-meta-item-body"][1]/text()'
```

but I'm getting stuck at the other two highlighted tags.

What should be done here or what would be the XPATH of the other tags with similar class and tag?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove index (`[1]`) to make your XPath applicable for all required nodes

```
//div[@class="recipe-meta-item-body"]/text()
```

Comment: i want the output to be { 'preptime': 10min, 'cooktime': 10min, 'servings':'6'} the out comes in chunk of number

Comment: @abctrial then you need to get both text nodes from parent `//div[@class="recipe-meta-item"]//text()` or separately first `//div[@class="recipe-meta-item-header"]/text()` and second `//div[@class="recipe-meta-item-body"]/text()` value

Answer (score 0):

To get output in chunks "preptime: 10min", "cooktime: 10min", "servings:'6" use this XPath:

```
//div[@class="recipe-meta-item"]/text()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [5]: response.xpath('//div[@class="recipe-meta-item"]/*/text()').getall()
Out[5]: 
['prep:',
 '10 mins ',
 'cook:',
 '15 mins ',
 'total:',
 '25 mins ',
 'Servings:',
 '6 ',
 'Yield:',
 '6 servings ']
```